# O que essa definição de recurso realmente quer dizer?

Tags: aplicação-web, http, rest

Estou estudando sobre API's web e REST e o livro que estou lendo fala o seguinte:

> A Web é construída em torno de três conceitos principais: recursos, URI's, e representações.
>
> Um recurso é qualquer coisa que tem uma URI. Um recurso em si é um mapeamento conceitual para uma ou mais entidades

Isso me deixou bastante em dúvida. Eu sempre achei que um recurso era a entidade em si. Por exemplo, temos um arquivo `index.html` que tem uma URI `servidor.com/index.html`, eu achava que o recurso em si seria esse arquivo.

Outro exemplo do mesmo tipo seria termos um objeto `Cliente` que pode ser recuperado de um banco de dados através de uma URI contendo seu ID `servidor.com/api/clientes/123`, novamente eu achava que o recurso seria o objeto retornado.

Por outro lado, eu sei que uma certa URI pode simplesmente receber dados e executar algum tipo de ação no servidor, sem retornar ou modificar uma entidade persistida no servidor. O livro inclusive da um exemplo disso

> Um recurso pode ser um serviço que prove uma interface para qualquer coisa como um catalogo, um dispositivo (e.g., uma impressora), um abridor wireless para uma porta de garagem...

Tanto no caso da impressora quanto da porta de garagem, não existe de fato uma entidade no servidor. A URI simplesmente vai permitir a execução de algum código.

O que significa um recurso ser um mapeamento conceitual para uma ou mais entidades?

**Edição:** Pensando um pouco sobre isso cheguei na seguinte forma de pensar: um recurso é qualquer coisa que pode ser alcançada a partir de uma URL. Por exemplo, a página inicial de um site, ou um cliente com certo ID. O recurso não é o arquivo `index.html` em si, nem o objeto JSON contendo os dados do cliente, porque essas duas coisas são somente o estado dele naquele momento (são representações), assim o recurso é na realidade o conceito que está por trás desses estados: tanto a página, quanto o cliente.

É isso que é um recurso? Se sim, por que isso pode ser considerado um mapeamento conceitual para uma ou mais entidades?

Comment: Tem URL e tem URI. Os conceitos são um pouco diferente. Aqui uma pagina em Ingles que coloca um pouco de luz sobre isso.
http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/URI

Comment: Obrigado @Peter, eu sei, URI's podem ser tanto URL's quanto URN's. Com relação à URI's e representações eu acho que eu entendi a ideia. O que eu não estou entendendo muito bem é por que um recurso é um mapeamento para uma ou mais entidades.

Comment: "Tanto no caso da impressora quanto da porta de garagem, não existe de fato uma interface no servidor.". Acho que sim, tem. Tenta formatar o HD totalmente, e depois ligar a impressora. Nada vai sair no papel. Tem um interface "software" (driver) e tem também um interface física para comunicar. Mesmo coisa com o teclado (antigamente tipo ACIA 6850 por exemplo). Então podemos provavelmente dizer que o ACIA 6850 e um "recurso" físico do tipo "input". Não bem facil, mas interesante! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confusões terminológicas como essa são comuns, especialmente com termos tão amplos e no contexto da web, cujas especificações sempre sucedem o próprio uso, e não o contrário. No início, *resource* não era sequer definido em especificação alguma. Existia uma noção geral de que URLs (ainda "Universais" e não "Uniformes") apontavam para algum recurso físico, como um arquivo em disco.

Mais adiante, foram aparecendo outros usos, e URIs foram definidas como "mapeamento conceitual" na [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) de 1998. Ela também diz que o recurso é "qualquer coisa que tem uma identidade" (cujo *identificador* é o próprio URI). Era uma forma de tentar dizer um URI não precisa corresponder a algo físico (como uma pessoa ou uma série de dados) ou mesmo concreto; pode até representar um conceito.

Esses termos devem ter dado confusão, porque na versão de 2005 ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) acabaram removidos e foi inserida uma definição que nem tenta mais definir nada:

> Esta especificação não limita o escopo do que possa ser considerado um recurso; o termo "recurso" é utilizado em sentido geral para qualquer coisa que possa ser identificada por um URI.

É isso, pode ser qualquer coisa. Se você olhar o [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/), por exemplo, URIs representam qualquer coisa mesmo, incluindo muitos conceitos, como o de autoria. E os URIs nem precisam ser acessíveis via rede nenhuma, em protocolo nenhum. Em HTTP, por exemplo, podem sem problemas levar a um 404. Sobre você disse, que "o recurso é na realidade o conceito que está por trás desses estados", pode ser. Depende. A definição na norma atual é tão ampla que não restringe que se pense assim, ao mesmo tempo em que deixa espaço para usos que não se encaixam nessa interpretação. Leve sempre isso em consideração, não adianta ficar procurando a resposta definitiva sobre o que pode ser um recurso, pois o termo, dentro do contexto daquilo para que um URI pode apontar, é extremamente amplo.

---

**Referência adicional:** [Web resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource) na Wikipedia EN.